# Dynamic year-values when creating a customized column in power bi depending on the actual year

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, powerquery, data-transform

I want to aggregate three timebuckets to one. At the moment I create a customized column like this:

```
timebucketNEW = IF([timebucket] IN {"YtD", "BoY", "2023"}, "2024", [timebucket])
```

This is already working well for this year. But in 2025 the IF-clause should look like this:

```
timebucketNEW = IF([timebucket] IN {"YtD", "BoY", "2024"}, "2025", [timebucket])
```

Now, I don't want to change this IF-statement in each new year. How can I do this automatically or dynamically, like System_Year()-1 gives me the last year and System_Year() gives me the actual year.

**EDIT:** The year in the `timebucket` column is expanded by another year with each new year. The other previous years remain included in the column or data set.

Comment: Will the year switch over in the new Calendar Year or do you have a different Fiscal Year start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options for you.

Similar to @davidebacci answer, try (formatting to text solves it):

```
timebucketNEW =
  IF(
    [timebucket] IN {"YtD", "BoY", FORMAT(YEAR(TODAY())-1, "0")}, 
    FORMAT(TODAY(), "yyyy"),
    [timebucket]
  )
```

Alternatively, you may want to have a dedicated table for this.
Create a new Calculated Table with:

```
Dim Year = 
  ADDCOLUMNS(
    DISTINCT('YourTable'[timebucket]),
    "Year",
      IF(
        [timebucket] IN {"YtD", "BoY", FORMAT(YEAR(TODAY())-1, "0") }, 
        FORMAT(TODAY(), "YYYY"),
        [timebucket]
      )
  )
```

Then add a relationship between this new table and `YourTable` on the `[timebucket]` columns. You would then use this new table for slicers, filters, visual dimension etc...